# setting Dropdown mode on an extended Spinner view

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I am extending spinner to add some functionality, I am trying to make the spinner a dropdown rather than dialog. So i am changing the spinner mode to drop down.

When I use this constructor, i get an exception

```
<mypackage.mypackage.MultiSelectionSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="10dp" />


mySpinner = (MultiSelectionSpinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

public class MultiSelectionSpinner extends Spinner{
    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle,int mode) {
        super(context, attrs,defStyle,mode);
        simple_adapter = new CustomerMultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter(context,
                R.layout.customer_spinner_adapter_view, new ArrayList<String>() );
        ...
    }
```

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101:
>   Error inflating class mypackage.mypackage.MultiSelectionSpinner   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:603)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)      at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native
>   Method)   at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)      at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)      at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:320)
>     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)      at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
>     **at mypackage.mypackage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)    *(which is basically the declaration mySpinner = (MultiSelectionSpinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);)***
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
>     ... 12 more  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
>   [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet] 
>     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:397)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:568)   ...
>   33 more

This however, works well, except the spinner is in dialog mode

```
public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    simple_adapter = new CustomerMultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter(context,
            R.layout.customer_spinner_adapter_view, new ArrayList<String>() );
    super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is an error at line 101 in your spinner xml file. Check to see if everything is set up correctly.